# OpenVPN Server IP Changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, openvpn

I just tried to set up an OpenVPN on AWS ec2.  However, the public IP address changed every time I start the ec2 and I cannot connect to the OpenVPN with my connection client software on my windows PC.  Any ideas on how to update the "OpenVPN Connect"?

Answer (score 1):

As each reboot will get you a 'new' IP address, you can have a cron script at @reboot that will reconfigure the openvpn server

```
@reboot at now + 1 min -f /path/to/script.sh
```

`/path/to/script.sh`

```
# gets the current public ip assigned to your instance 
INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)


cd /usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts

# updates the server hostname with your public IP
./sacli --key "host.name" --value $INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP ConfigPut

# restart the server
./sacli start
```

Answer (score 0):

When an Amazon EC2 instance is launched, it can be assigned a public IP address. This will be a random address. Therefore, whenever the instance is Stopped and Started, it will change its public IP address.

If you want to keep the Public IP address the same, then you should:

- Create an **Elastic IP address** (which is static)
- Associated the Elastic IP address to the Amazon EC2 instance

The EC2 instance will then keep the same Public IP address, even when it is Stopped and Started.

Comment: Thx.  What if I don't want to use elastic IP?  Any way to modify openVPN connection to reflect the public IP change?

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the @reboot solution above to work, but discovered another solution.

Basically, I think the OpenVPN server is actually handling the change of IPv4 when you restart the instance just fine.

But the **Host Name** is set as *the IPv4 address that the instance had on deployment*.

There is parameter on OpenVPN Connect to help handle this (server override).

When you want to connect your VPN, edit the relevant profile in OpenVPN Connect so that:

**user:** [username]

**pass:** [password]

**server host name:** [the public ipv4 at deployment] (which remains the host name on the server. You can find this by logging into the VPN admin panel and going to network settings)

**server override:** [current public-ipv4] (actual ip address from instance launch)

**port:** (presumably) 943

You will have to put the new IPv4 into **server override** with each instance start, but this surely the easiest way.